# How can i force circleci to use a new github default branch?

Tags: caching, github, continuous-integration, circleci

We changed our default branch from master to develop. it seems that circleci uses still the cache from master for new branches. Is there a posibility to force circleci to use another default branch?

Answer (score 0):

The Circle cache is shared among all branches so it wouldn't be possible to have separate caches. If you need the cache wiped though you can contact Circle support at sayhi@circleci.com

Comment: Here they write that every branch has its own cache: https://circleci.com/docs/how-cache-works#per-branch-cache.

Comment: The page that Sean linked shows how to you can rebuild the cache for the branch. Through the UI and circle.yml file. That will force the change as you requested.